# Incorporating mpi into time and space big O notation

Tags: algorithm, mpi, big-o

If I have to do n simulations, where each simulation has m steps, I would say that this process will take O(n*m) time without message passing. With mpi enabled, each of the n steps can be paralyzed, although the m steps must be in series. Would it be correct to say that, with j communicators, this process would take O( (n/j) * m ) time? I am not sure if it is correct to dive n by j here. Is there anything I can definitively say about scaling of memory in this scenario?

Comment: Can that be formalized with big O space and time costs?

Answer (score 0):

There's actually two answers.  When it comes to parallel code, it's helpful to learn about network sorting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network.  The key thing for your question is that there are two ways to measure network efficiency: the total number of comparitors (`O(n*m)`), or the depth (`O( (n/j) * m )`.  Both are accurate, you just have to be clear which you are talking about.

I am not familiar with monte carlo simulations, so I can't talk about memory specifically, but usually when you make something parallel, memory usage goes up, not down.  If it's "perfectly parallizable" memory goes up slightly from process overhead, and if you're unlucky, memory usage may be directly proportional to `j`, Or even worse!

Comment: What factors would determine if the space would scale with j? Would this be O(j * m)?

Comment: It depends entirely on what the algorithm is and how it works. Since I'm not familiar with Monte Carlo, I don't really know how to clarify. The question is very related to "how much memory does Monte Carlo take with j threads?" but I don't know the answer.

Comment: The important info is that there are n parallel processes which each take m steps.